# Foreign Key for joined/combined/link datasets

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two main tables, one that holds `products` and one that holds the `costs` associated with the products. The problem is that I need a link table to combine the two (the `lookup` table) as costs only knows codes whereas products only knows classes.
(this construct is for historical data reasons...)

I need to construct a foreign key that makes sure that there is a price for every product.

A simple MWE would be (without FKs for now)

```
-- only has class; no code...
CREATE TABLE products (
  class TEXT NOT NULL,
  color TEXT NOT NULL,
  price REAL,
  UNIQUE(class)
  -- THIS is what I want; but b.c. COMBINED is a view and not a table, I get
  -- the error later
  -- FOREIGN KEY (class, color) REFERENCES COMBINED (class, color)
);
 
-- only code no class...
CREATE TABLE costs (
  code TEXT NOT NULL,
  color TEXT NOT NULL,
  cost REAL,
  UNIQUE(code, color)
);

-- link table for products and costs
CREATE TABLE lookup (
  class TEXT NOT NULL,
  code TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(class)
);

CREATE VIEW COMBINED AS
  SELECT costs.code, lookup.class, costs.color
  FROM costs LEFT JOIN lookup ON costs.class = lookup.class;
```

Then, the test data:

```
INSERT INTO lookup (class, code) VALUES ('AAA', 'aaa'), ('BBB', 'bbb');
INSERT INTO costs (code, color, cost) VALUES ('aaa', 'red', 123), ('bbb', 'blue', 456);
INSERT INTO products (class, color, price) VALUES ('AAA', 'red', 0.123); -- should work
INSERT INTO products (class, color, price) VALUES ('CCC', 'red', 0.456); -- expect FK error on CCC
```

When I use the foreign key as commented-out, I get the error `foreign key mismatch - "products" referencing "COMBINED"` as COMBINED is a view and not a table.

Is there any way to achieve this or do I need to play around with triggers to make sure that costs always have a matching column?

Answer (score 1):

i still think you made it too complicated

the lockup table is a bridge table

```
CREATE VIEW COMBINED AS
  SELECT costs.code, lookup.class 
  FROM costs LEFT JOIN lookup ON costs.class = lookup.class;
```

```
CREATE TABLE costs (
  code TEXT NOT NULL,
  cost REAL,
  UNIQUE(code)
);
```

✓

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  class TEXT NOT NULL,
  price REAL,
  UNIQUE(class)
);
```

✓

```
 PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

✓

```
CREATE TABLE lookup (
  class TEXT NOT NULL,
  code TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(class, code),

 FOREIGN KEY (class) REFERENCES products (class),

 FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES costs (code)
);
```

✓

```
INSERT INTO costs (code, cost) VALUES ('aaa', 123), ('bbb', 456);
```

✓

```
INSERT INTO products (class, price) VALUES ('AAA', 0.123); -- should work
```

✓

```
INSERT INTO products (class, price) VALUES ('BBB', 0.346); -- should work
```

✓

```
INSERT INTO products (class, price) VALUES ('CCC', 0.456); -- expect FK error on CCC
```

✓

```
INSERT INTO lookup (class, code) VALUES ('AAA', 'aaa');
```

✓

```
INSERT INTO lookup (class, code) VALUES  ('BBB', 'bbb');
```

✓

```
INSERT INTO lookup (class, code) VALUES  ('DDD','ddd');
```

> ```
> {
>   "code": "SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY"
> }
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YHz5aqr7)